# get yLabel value onclick chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to have the y label value, when I click on the bar.

[image: <code>barImage</code>]

Like the above example, when I click on feb blue bar I want to have label value, which is 40

I looked for examples on stackOverFlow  and other sites but they only have example of label for the legend show up.

some of the code I tried

```
onClick: function(evt, element) {
      var activePoints = bar_chart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
      console.log(activePoints[0]._model.datasetLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This demo gives the value in the bar chart when you click on it.
I'm not a chart.js expert so there may be better solutions.

https://codepen.io/newschapmj1/pen/PerOzM

```
/* from https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2292 */
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function (evt) {
        var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'point', myChart.options);
        var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
        var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
        var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
        alert(label + ": " + value);
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

Chart.js version = 3.2.1

From the [official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html):

> ```
> onClick: (evt) => {
>     const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
>
>     if (points.length) {
>         const firstPoint = points[0];
>         var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
>         var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
>         alert(label +" : "+ value);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to get the chart from the callback because I'm using the same callback for multiple charts, so I can't just say `myChart`

This works, passing to chart options - the second parameter is called "activeElements" and can be used to get the chart:

```
onClick: (event, activeElements) => {
    if(activeElements.length === 0){
      alert("Chart is clickable but you must click a data point to drill-down")
    }
    const chart = activeElements[0]._chart
    const activePoints = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event, 'point', chart.options);
    const firstPoint = activePoints[0];
    const label = chart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
    const value = chart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
    alert(label + ": " + value);
}
```

Comment: You get the chart as a third argument in the onClick function, it is a better practice to use that one then to acess a private property which can get removed without a major version increase

Answer (score 0):

Mix between mikeb and Mrunalraj Redij answers. Add Hover and use 'index' and 'intersect: false' to select the value even if the mouse pointer is not on the line.

```
chartClickHoverCB(event, activeElements, chart) {
      const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(event, 'index', { intersect: false }, true);

      if (points.length) {
          const firstPoint = points[0];
          var label = chart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
          var value = chart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
          console.log(label +" : "+ value);
      }
  }


chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    ....
    onClick: this.chartClickHoverCB,
    onHover: this.chartClickHoverCB,
  };
```